# thead, tfoot and tbody order in HTML5

Tags: html

I was reading [in a forum](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?855199-THEAD-TBODY-TFOOT) about `<tfoot>` element that it must  come after `<thead>` element. In contrast I saw some people use the order `<thead><tbody><tfoot>`. So what is the correct and best to follow order?

Comment: head, body, foot. When they say 'after' it doesn't mean straight after, just not before.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Before HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1), `<tfoot>` had to come after `<thead>` and before `<tbody>`. With [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/tabular-data.html#the-table-element), `<tfoot>` can come before `<tbody>` or after it. But there must be only one `<tfoot>` child of a `<table>` element, and it must be after `<thead>`.

Comment: For readers that aren't inclined to scroll further: as of Dec 2015 the spec no longer allows the pre-HTML5 behavior [due to accessibility issues](https://github.com/whatwg/html/commit/94d55af9cda601ce675d15f6a0e52c9bb9c6afa9) (this change is reflected in W3C HTML 5.1 and later), and validators now enforce this by emitting an error when encountering a tbody after a tfoot in a document with the living doctype.

Answer (score 5):

According to the W3 specs, `tfoot` has to come before `tbody`. (Links to specs here -> [Why do internal TABLE sections have to go THEAD TFOOT TBODY to validate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574057/why-do-internal-table-sections-have-to-go-thead-tfoot-tbody-to-validate))

This was done to allow the header and footer of a table to load first, before loading in a variable amount of body data, which would otherwise possibly block the loading of the table footer.

Comment: I like @Alohci's answer too.

Comment: According the W3 specs, in HTML5 it may also coma after the `tbody` tag! And this question is about HTML5.. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tfoot-element

Comment: @Timo002,  Where in the original question is html5 stated?  I don't see any reference to html5 in the OP, only 'html'.  I only see a reference to html5 in Alochi's answer.

Comment: @PerryTew The question was specifically about HTML5. Answers that address other versions should mention what versions they mean explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

In the HTML 5.1 spec, `<tfoot>` can only come after `<tbody>`.

> In this order: optionally a caption element, followed by zero or more colgroup elements, followed optionally by a thead element, followed by either zero or more tbody elements or one or more tr elements, followed optionally by a tfoot element, optionally intermixed with one or more script-supporting elements.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/tabular-data.html#tabular-data

Comment: The documentation you link to does not support your statement that `<tfoot>` can only come after `<tbody>`. In fact, the documentation explicitly states that the closing `</tfoot>` tag can be omitted if the element is **followed** by a `<tbody>` tag.

Comment: @Paul Rowe: Regardless, every known validator now emits an error when encountering a tbody that follows a tfoot. I suspect that statement about end tags was left in there to accommodate legacy behavior, i.e. for when a tbody could still follow a tfoot. Apparently the restriction was added [due to accessibility issues that was causing](https://github.com/whatwg/html/commit/94d55af9cda601ce675d15f6a0e52c9bb9c6afa9).