# Can I ignore the <tbody> element in HTML 5?

Tags: html

i have seen some *HTML5* designers ignoring the element `<tbody>` when marking up a table. They only use the `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` elements instead. Can this be considered a good practice and following good standards in HTML5?

---

This question based on **my previous question** which can be found at:

[thead, tfoot and tbody order in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901950/thead-tfoot-and-tbody-order-in-html5)

- My previous question was about the order of using `<thead><tbody><tfoot>` and this question is about the possibilty of removing the `<tbody>` at all from the markup.

Comment: [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7491000/497418)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-table-element.html#the-table-element), it states clearly about `table`

> In this order: optionally a caption element, followed by zero or more
>   colgroup elements, followed optionally by a thead element, followed
>   optionally by a tfoot element, **followed by either zero or more tbody**
>   elements or one or more tr elements, followed optionally by a tfoot
>   element (but there can only be one tfoot element child in total).

It's optional but good practice to explicitly add it, as other answer also mentioned that, I agree with [zzzzBov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497418/zzzzbov).

Answer (score 6):

The `<tbody>` element will automatically be inserted around `<tr>` elements if you do not add it, in the same way that `<body>` will be wrapped around the contents of the page.

It is for this reason that I recommend explicitly adding `<tbody>` elements, so that there is no confusion when an implied `tbody` element gets styled in CSS.

Comment: @SheikhHeera, not a problem; it's easy to misread. I can't tell you how many times people have called me "zzzzBoy", which I find absolutely infuriating.

Comment: I've made it better now.

Comment: This is almost a “primarily ipinion-based” question, but the point about avoiding confusion is a rather solid technical argument in favor of explicit `<tbody>` tags. It matters in scripting and styling, acting as a reminder: a `tr` element is never a child of a `table` element.