# MPDF error Message: must precede in a table

Tags: mpdf

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Mpdf\MpdfException

Message: must precede in a table

Filename: /home/press.altisinfonet.com/public_html/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php

Line Number: 13410

Backtrace:

File: /home/press.altisinfonet.com/public_html/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php
Line: 23545
Function: TableHeaderFooter

File: /home/press.altisinfonet.com/public_html/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Tag/Table.php
Line: 1121
Function: _tableWrite

File: /home/press.altisinfonet.com/public_html/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Tag.php
Line: 246
Function: close

File: /home/press.altisinfonet.com/public_html/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php
Line: 15272
Function: CloseTag

File: /home/press.altisinfonet.com/public_html/app/libraries/Tec_mpdf.php
Line: 68
Function: WriteHTML

File: /home/press.altisinfonet.com/public_html/app/libraries/Sma.php
Line: 302
Function: generate

File: /home/press.altisinfonet.com/public_html/app/controllers/admin/Sales.php
Line: 418
Function: generate_pdf

File: /home/press.altisinfonet.com/public_html/index.php
Line: 303
Function: require_once
```

Comment: May be its a template issue !!  check your table tbody thead tr td tfoot are closed  correctly !!

Comment: Next time when asking a question, an exception stack trace is certainly not enough, add a small code example reproducing the behaviour - see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18901950/2943403

Answer (score 1):

In newer mPDF versions (or in a plaintext rendering), the message of this exception is `<tfoot> must precede <tbody> in a table`.

By HTML 4 specification, the order of table elements has to be `<thead>` → `<tfoot>` → `<tbody>` (this directly contradicts HTML 5 specification where the order is `<thead>` → `<tbody>` → `<tfoot>`).

mPDF adheres to the HTML 4 in this matter.

Put yout `<tbody>` to the end of the table and the exception will not be thrown.

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tfoot